# the app on my phone continuously crashing when ever i try to run my app in android studio and showing this in the logcat

Tags: android, kotlin

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.asp, PID: 20198
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.asp/com.example.asp.Spash.Splashscreen}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.asp.Spash.Splashscreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~5DiuWqfvqfve5_hJfyIyIQ==/com.example.asp-cigXcT0OFONsezhteTZm4A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~5DiuWqfvqfve5_hJfyIyIQ==/com.example.asp-cigXcT0OFONsezhteTZm4A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4051)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.asp.Spash.Splashscreen" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~5DiuWqfvqfve5_hJfyIyIQ==/com.example.asp-cigXcT0OFONsezhteTZm4A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~5DiuWqfvqfve5_hJfyIyIQ==/com.example.asp-cigXcT0OFONsezhteTZm4A==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1328)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4038)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8757) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067) 
2023-07-26 10:22:36.827 20198-20231 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.asp                      D  RenderThread::setGrContext()

I don't know what to do please help me

Comment: Hi & welcome to StackOverflow. Please extend your question to show us your code, otherwise we won't be able to help you

Comment: can you help me i really need help because this is for my final project

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your activity "com.example.asp.Spash.Splashscreen" to your manifest ?
If not, do that and retry.

the manifest is usually located at "/your_project_folder/your_module/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"

add the activity item under the  tag, like below,

```
<application>
    //other stuff
    <activity android:name=".Spash.Splashscreen"
              android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    //other stuff
</applcation>
```